# ionic range component not showing values as it is changed

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to print to the console the value of the range position as I move the slider using the "ionChange" event  but 2 things are happening:

1- I see a lot f warnings like this in the console:

```
vendor.js:66869 [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

2- the method only prints when I stop moving the slider, I can not print to the console all the values the range is going through, not even the "steps" values

This is what I have inside the 'content' tags:

```
<ion-range min="1" max="180" [(ngModel)]="position" color="secondary" (ionChange)="rangeChanged($event)" step="10" debounce="500">
  <ion-label range-left>1</ion-label>
  <ion-label range-right>180</ion-label>
</ion-range>
<ion-item>
  Value = {{position}}
</ion-item>
```

and this is the code in my "rangeChanged" function:

```
  rangeChanged($event){
    console.log("Position1: ", $event);
    console.log("Position2: ", this.position);

  }
```

I am using these versions:

```
C:\Users\user\rangeExample>ionic -v
3.19.0

C:\Users\user\rangeExample>cordova -v
8.0.0
```

I googled it and only see old posts but none address my issue, please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngModelChange` instead of `ionChange`.

```
<ion-range min="1" max="180" [(ngModel)]="position" color="secondary" (ngModelChange)="rangeChanged($event)" step="10" debounce="500">
  <ion-label range-left>1</ion-label>
  <ion-label range-right>180</ion-label>
</ion-range>
```

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rti9fq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) 
& here is my output [image]

Comment: thank you, a little better (shows the position value a little more, like 4 or 5 times instead of one) but still tons of warnings

Comment: You need to learn how to use the Dev tools of your browser. I f you're using chrome go to console then go to all levels & disable verbose

Comment: yes it is a warning, and by disabling the warning level in chrome dev tools "it goes away" but it still there, nonetheless I would like to know what is causing it to get rid of it, also in the browser you dont see  that warning only on the phones

Comment: The warnings are coming from using ionic component & depends on the device only(performance, speed..) I suggest you learn the framework first.